# Smilite functions not working under Windows

Tags: python

Although I apparently managed to install Python smilite package, none of the functions seem to work. Is there a way to test whether the installation is complete or not? What could I do to make it working?

Smilite is a small python package that allow conversion of ZINC database IDs (a database of chemical compounds, where each substance has its own ID, as a string) to SMILES (a chemical representation of the substance structure, in essence the chemical formula as a string).

I installed smilite via "pip install git+https://github.com/rasbt/smilite.git", as recommended here: https://github.com/rasbt/smilite/issues/2

According to the documentation "After you installed the smilite module, you can import it in Python via import smilite", then its functions should be available. My importation (under Windows 7) was reported as successful, but after I (successfully, no error message) import the module (import smilite), no function seems to be available. For instance, running "lookup_zincid (ZINC01234567)" I receive an error: "NameError: name 'lookup_zincid' is not defined", although according to the documentation it should be defined and imported.

Comment: Did you try `smilite.lookup_zincid("ZINC01234567")`?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately  module 'smilite' has no attribute 'lookup_zincid'.

Comment: What does `dir(smilite)` print out?

Comment: Thank you for your help. It seems I get some light now. Here is what it prints: ['__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 '__spec__',
 '__version__',
 'check_duplicate_smiles',
 'comp_two_csvfiles',
 'create_id_smile_list',
 'create_sqlite',
 'generate_zincid_smile_csv',
 'get_zinc_smile',
 'get_zincid_from_smile',
 'insert_id_sqlite',
 'lookup_id_sqlite',
 'lookup_smile_sqlite',
 'simplify_smile',
 'smilite',
 'sqlite_to_csv',
 'sqlite_to_dict']

​

Comment: I tried smilite.get_zinc_smile("ZINC01234567"), now in theory it works, but I receive an "Invalid ZINC ID ZINC000001550477" message (although the ZINC ID is valid.

Comment: I tried it for other ZINC IDs and I continue to get the same message (ZINC ID not valid).

Comment: It seems I managed to make it run now: it doesn't work anymore with the implicit value of the database version (Zinc12), but it works if I add 'zinc15' as the second argument. Thank you for your help, you helped me make it work. I am not sure your answer is formulated as an answer (so that I could accept it) or only as a comment (I tend to believe is only a comment). If I am wrong, please tell me.

Comment: Do not worry, glad you could partially solve your problem. I didn't do much here, just pointed out some well known steps. If you manage to solve your problem and make it work, you could answer your own question, with all the details (for example I know nothing about *smilite*).